# Keep lines together with float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I try to achieve a non line breaking paragraph.

So I have a image on the left side with float:left and multiple paragraphs on the right side which wrap around the picture if they are too long. This is good and should stay like this.
But I want to keep the lines of one paragraph together.

So right now, when I resize the window, only the last line of my last paragraph is beneath the picture.
I want the whole last paragraph to be beneath the picture if there is not enough space to keep it side by side.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome. Please [edit] your question and post the code you use so we can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to share code here. so people can test it. You need to use clear method when you use float. check on The clear property specifies what elements can float beside the cleared element and on which side. Check documentation about clear and float

Answer (score 0):

(Edit queue is full, so I'll post my edit here:)

I try to achieve a non line breaking paragraph.

**Situation:**
I have an image on the left side with `float:left` and multiple paragraphs on the right side which wrap around the picture if they are too long. This is good and should stay like this.
But I want to keep the lines of one paragraph together.

**Problem:**
When I resize the window, only the last line of my last paragraph is beneath the picture.
*I want the whole last paragraph to be beneath the picture if there is not enough space to keep it side by side*.

#### Image: Current

[image]

#### Image: Goal

[image]

#### Code

```
<div style="float:left">
<img src="img.png" />
</div>
<p> Paragraph 1. la la la la la la </p>
<p> Paragraph 2. la la la la la la </p>
<p> Paragraph 3. la la la la la la </p>
```